# How do I calculate a ratio from 2 numbers and return an equivalent list of about 1000 numbers?

Tags: python, calculation

I was online at this amazing site for equivalent ratios.  I would love to mimic or do the same as an output in python, but its a bit over my skills.

Can you help me put it in this format, here is what the first 3 pairs would look like in the output in python, if you can help me please?  I'm using python37

1 : 5618    2 : 11236   3 : 16854

Here is the site that does what I want:
https://goodcalculators.com/ratio-calculator/

Here is my code so far but I hope someone can help me so it prints out in a nice fancy format or just maybe a cool list of numbers in equivalent ratio format:

It is throwing an error and I don't know why, and this is the error:

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' Enter 1st number for ratio calculation: '**

```
    while True:
        a = input(int(' Enter 1st number for ratio calculation: '))
        b = input(int(' Enter 2nd number for ratio calculation: '))
        r = ( a/b and b/b)
        print(r)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ints should be first:

```
   while True:
        a = int(input(' Enter 1st number for ratio calculation: '))
        b = int(input(' Enter 2nd number for ratio calculation: '))
        r = ( a/b and b/b)
        print(r)
```

For the calculator you can do something like this:

```
list_numbers={}
ratio1 = 1
ratio2 = 3698
for x in range(1,100):
   list_numbers.update({ratio1*x: ratio2*x})
```

Comment: oppressionslayer you have been helping me a great deal lately so how to a create a list of a 1000 numbers like this small example,  1 : 5618 2 : 11236 3 : 16854

Comment: do you want a list or set, [ [1,5618] ], [ 2, 11236 ], [3, 16854]]  or set { 1:5618, 2:11236}, {3,16854}  and are those just random numbers? I'd use a for loop

Comment: Well the first input would be [1]  2nd is [ 3698 ]

Comment: Yes please beginning with these first inputs like ratio for goodcalculators

Comment: I think i just updated it do that, you can modify it to use your inputs a and b

Comment: You are so awesome oppressionslayer, you take the oppression away from python coding :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two functions according to the versions of the python you have on your system. 
Python3 has input() and python2 has raw_input() which **returns the string objects only**. so that you need to explicitly convert it to the integer. For python3 you can do as below and for python2 you can use eval() function ahead of raw_input() so that you can evaluate the expression.

```
while True:
    a = int(input(' Enter 1st number for ratio calculation: '))
    b = int(input(' Enter 2nd number for ratio calculation: '))
    r = ( a/b and b/b)
    print(r)
```

Python2:

```
x=1
print eval('x+1') ==> 2
```